# Is it okay if I normalize whole dataset together?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, data-science, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to train a RNN network which employs LSTMs.

In data preprocessing part, when I normalize(feature scaling) the dataset, I am normalizing whole database together. However, **I have serious doubts if some of the input columns are dominant on others**, and it can effect the network training part. Here is an example of the dataset for better understanding:

[image: Example part of the dataset]

As you can see from the figure above, different colored columns are much more greater or lower than others.

So, my question is; is it okay if I normalize the whole dataset together, or should I normalize each columns individually?

Comment: By normalize, are you referring to [feature scaling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling)? In that case, you should apply the operations on a per-feature (each column) basis.

Comment: Thanks for making it clear. I have editted the question and pointed out it is feature scaling. And much appriciated for the answer! Now I found out what was I doing wrong along the whole way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feature scaling is done on a per column basis. The operations are applied to one feature at a time because the objective is to get the different features into similar ranges so the unit of the feature does not impact learning ([source](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/468/2145/2630)). You are right that the magnitude of  features can affect training and therefore scaling is considered a best practice especially when training neural networks.

Typically this is done in one of two ways:

- Rescaling: making the values of a feature fall into a range, for example from 0 to 1. Min-Max rescaling accomplishes this by:

[image: Rescaling]

- Standardization: subtracting the mean and dividing by the standard deviation. The new feature will have a mean of 0 and a standard deviation of 1.

[image: Standardization]

Rescaling can be done in Python using Scikit-Learn's [`MinMaxScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MinMaxScaler.html). Standardization can be done in Python using Scikit-Learn's [`StandardScaler`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html).

Here is a good article on the basics of feature scaling: http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html.